# Enforce tunneling SSH user directly into docker container

Tags: ssh, docker, ssh-tunnel

We want to setup a gitlab installation with their official docker images. To support connection to git repositories via SSH we see two options.

1. Bind container port 22 to host port 22
2. Bind container port 22 to another host port

If we decide for solution 1 we would loose the possibility to SSH to the host machine, which is unacceptable.
For solution 2 we could configure gitlab properly, to know which port to display to a user, still it feels less convenient to connect to `ssh://git@githost:1234:user/repo` instead of connecting to `git@githost:user/repo`.

Now we thought there might be a possibility where we can configure openssh on server side to always forward/tunnel ssh connections for a specific user (git) to connect to the docker container.

The only progress we could make is getting a login session to directly connect to the container by setting default "shell" from `/etc/passwd` to run a `docker exec` for the container. But since git does not open a login shell this is not working for git commands.

Comment: 3. Bind host port 22 to another host port.